# Component in Angular on click it is taking whole arrays as selected not only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am implementing a rating component in Angular, which I'll use in another component to rate the language.
Rate I mean how good is with it.

My problem it is that when I do hear a click event for one array, automatically will select the second array and give them both or will fill both of them with color.
It is possible to click only one event and give it data.
The code for star component I am based in this stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-star-rating-kptyy2?file=app%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Here is my `star` component.

```
<button mat-icon-button *ngFor="let ratingId of ratingArr;index as i" [id]="'star_'+i" (click)="onClick(i+1)"
        >
  <mat-icon>
    {{showIcon(i)}}
  </mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-error *ngIf="starCount == null || starCount == 0">
</mat-error>

export class StarRatingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("rating") private rating = 3;
  @Input("starCount") public starCount = 5;
  @Output() private ratingUpdated = new EventEmitter();

  public ratingArr = [];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.starCount; index++) {
      this.ratingArr.push(index);
    }
  }
  onClick(rating: number) {
    this.ratingUpdated.emit(rating);
    return false;
  }

  showIcon(index: number) {
    if (this.rating >= index + 1) {
      return "star";
    } else {
      return "star_border";
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the component which I try to show it and fill with data.

```
<div *ngFor="let language of subCategory.languages; let i = index">
        <div class="col-md-8">
         {{language.name}}
         <app-star-rating [rating]="language.rate" [starCount]="starCount" (ratingUpdated)="onRatingChanged($event)"></app-star-rating>
        </div>
      </div>

  onRatingChanged(rating) {
    this.skills.subCategories.map(test => test.languages.filter(res => {
      console.log(res.name);
      res.rate = rating;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi and How would be that possible ?

Comment: could you please help me understand what are the two arrays you are referring to here?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I do have two arrays.
First has an id, name and rate
Name: English, rate: 2
Name: German, rate: 5
rate will show the icons(star)

Comment: Code you shared in stack blitz does not talk about the problem you have stated above. It runs completely fine . Could you please add that code also in the stack blitz ? Also if possible the structure of skills object

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Oke i will do it.
As tip try to add another component in stackblitz and u will see that will select both of rating component.

Comment: Is this what you mean , I added the component test , but the star rating component is behaving properly for me ? https://angular-material-star-rating-kddwqe.stackblitz.io .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220811/discussion-between-harmandeep-singh-kalsi-and-nideba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index from the HTML in the **onRatingChanged** function along with event as below:

```
 <div *ngFor="let language of languages; let i = index">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         {{language.name}}
         <mat-star-rating [rating]="language.rate" [color]="starColor" (ratingUpdated)="onRatingChanged($event,i)"></mat-star-rating>
      </div>
 </div>
```